# How to stress test google drive app for 100,000 business users?

Tags: google-drive-api

We have build a application for google drive and it is already in use, Now I want to test this for 100,000 business users, if I buy a paid account it costs $5 per user per month
Is there a way google can provide me help in testing my app for 100,000 enterprise users.

Answer (score 0):

As with any other development process you can take a best guess, test on a smaller scale and try extrapolating.

Once your users start getting in the thousands it will be obvious and the small-scale testing will get you to the thousands.

Don't think this is one big preemptive test setup, think of continuously improving and scaling your system

Comment: But this will not solve my problem, We are using almost all Google drive features and we have user activities. We need a environment where 100,000 users are using kind of real google drive

Comment: Maybe you're misreading my answer: I think this is the *only* practical approach to your situation. I can't imagine you'd create 100K accounts just for testing - you'll get your google account suspended. All you can do is incrementally improve your system and your performance guess to the point where you can claim it can support 100K users with decent confidence